# Python GUI Tkinter error: self.text=Text(self, width=35, height=2, wrap =WORD) TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'wrap'

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, textbox

I can get my GUI window to open just fine when i remove `self.text=Text(self,width=35, height=2,wrap=WORD)` and that line runs fine in another program. But in the main progaram i am working on i would like some text boxes and I get this error:

```
self.text=Text(self, width=35, height=2, wrap =WORD)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'wrap'
```

How can I resolve this? It runs in another .py file so I don't think reinstalling python will help

Comment: Do you have a class called `Text` in your program?

Comment: If I delete the argument wrap, it returns the same error about height.

Comment: not a class defined by me. I am using the tkinter package which defines `Text`

Comment: check your imports, you are surely not calling tkinter's Text, when you do `Text(..` .

Comment: If you take the time to create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that exercise will probably expose the error. You're importing something from somewhere that is overwriting the import of the tkinter widgets.

Comment: you were 100% right. I was importing nltk which has a Text function

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have some other class or function named `Text` in your program that is being used instead. You obviously aren't calling the tkinter `Text` class or you wouldn't get this error.

N.B. if you import tkinter as `import tkinter as tk` or `import Tkinter as tk` and then reference widgets with the prefix `tk.` (eg: `tk.Text(...)`) you won't ever have this type of problem. This is one of the reasons why wildcard imports are bad.

Comment: Thats it!! Using the NBayes nltk package which has a Text function i guess. Thank you!